# The timeout examples ( both IdleStateHandler and ReadTimeoutHandler ) in Netty3.2 API do not work for server

Tags: java, timer, timeout, netty

The timeout examples (both `IdleStateHandler` and `ReadTimeoutHandler`)  in Netty3.2 API do not work for server, only work for client. Who knows why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

They should work on the server side, too.  If it does not work, please let us know how to reproduce it by [creating a new issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues).